# React Native app on iOS quits with: “Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9”

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have a React Native application and since I updated for iOS 11 and Xcode 9 I'm experiencing a strange behavior. The app would quit after using it for a few minutes with the message on the Xcode console and no error message on the debbuger:

```
“Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9”
```

I'm aware that 'terminated due to signal 9'

> means that your app was terminated by a SIGKILL signal. The OS sends
>   that signal whenever your app is terminated involuntarily, whether
>   it's because of memory pressure (or several other reasons not relevant
>   to this discussion), or the user explicitly killing your app by double
>   tapping the Home button and swiping it away.

But I'm not sure why this is happening all the time while I'm debbuging the app.

Here are some other console messages that might be relevant:

```
[User Defaults] Couldn't write value for key ApplicationAccessibilityEnabled in CFPrefsPlistSource<0x1c411fd10> (Domain: com.apple.Accessibility, User: kCFPreferencesCurrentUser, ByHost: No, Container: (null), Contents Need Refresh: Yes): setting preferences outside an application's container requires user-preference-write or file-write-data sandbox access, switching to read-only
```

Does anybody know why that is happening?